# Calculadora Basal- Redondeo

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculo, redondeo

tengo una consulta respecto al trabajo de la calculadora basal en específico a la hora de poner el peso y que salgan los posibles resultados me sale con todos los decimales. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para redondear el resultado?

Comment: Bienvenido. Ya hay preguntas como la tuya. Revisa si alguna te sirve.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!